# Executing cross domain javascript never hits code in .done

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

@People downvoting this issue: what's wrong with it? Which info am I not providing?

I'm trying to do a cross-domain service call via javascript from domainA to domainX, but somehow the line `console.log('OK');` is never hit. The line `console.log('1');` is hit.

How can I make sure the line `console.log('OK');` is executed?

**www.domainA.com/test.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var ttScript = document.createElement('script'); ttScript.async = true;
        ttScript.src = '//www.domainX.com/js/test.js?v=1';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ttScript);
    })();
</script>
```

**www.domainX.com/js/test.js**

```
(function () {
    console.log('1');
    $.ajax({
        url: "//www.domainX.com/iplookup.php",
        data: null,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log('OK');
    });
})();
```

I tried `jsonp` and `json` as `dataType`. But when setting it to `json` or setting `crossDomain` to `false` I get:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.domainX.nl/iplookup.php?callback=jQuery1102023322901595383883_1419031985295&_=1419031985296. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

**www.domainX.com/iplookup.php**

I tried with and without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

```
<?php
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $data = json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    echo "jsonp_callback($data);";
    //print json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
?>
```

With the above configuration I get NO errors in my Chrome console.
Under network I see that the test.js is loaded succesfully when requesting page `www.domainA.com/test.aspx`

I checked under Net tab under the Response tab and I see the call being made to //www.domainX.com/iplookup.php" which returns the value I'd expect, in this case an IP address.

What more can I do?

Comment: so... add an error handler.

Comment: JSONP certainly won't work. The output is JSON.

Comment: JSON is not the same thing as JSONP. If using JSONP, you don't need CORS headers. the output you are returning currently is JSON, not JSONP. Seems like you're just throwing everything you can think of at it without thinking about what these options actually do.

Comment: Your PHP has errors in it. You can't output a blank line before you output more headers.

Comment: @KevinB error handlers do not work with JSONP. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: In what document will `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` return false? And if it did, why would `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` return true?

Comment: @KevinB: you mean in my PHP file? How would I return JSONP there?

Comment: @Quentin: I updated my post, I get no errors. Under Net tab I see the call being made to //www.domainX.com/iplookup.php" which returns the value I'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jsonp you are atually requesting a file like this:

```
 jsonp_callback(yourDataHere);
```

And this file is included into your document making the values accessible when the function is called.
So your php-file has to echo something like this:

```
<?php
    $data = json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    echo $_GET['jsonp_callback']."($data);";
?>
```

Note that you have to add the jsonp-function to the $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "//www.domainX.com/iplookup.php",
    async: false,
    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback', 
    dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Btw: Why would you do that call syncronous?

**Edit:** I wrote kinda crap. I updated my answer. The file you are requesting is just calling a function with your data as parameters. The callback is then the function itself. Jquery should normally handle that for you and make the data available in .done(). 
Read through the manual [here](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)!

Comment: So it looks like the code in function `jsonp_callback()` will actually be executed instead of the code I have in the `.done(function (data)` block? If so, how can I print the actual returned data to the console in the function `jsonp_callback()`? So where you now have `YourValuesHere`? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying the `.done` part should still contain code? Could you perhaps give a code example on how to print the data returned by iplookup.php to the console, including the `.done` part of the AJAX call? ps. your link to the manual does not work :)

Comment: Actually jsonp is not that hard to understand. Anyway - I edited my answer!

Comment: Thanks! That works! Will do some further testing and then award the bounty. :-D